# Good physics book to discover stuff by yourself

Tags: experimental-physics, resource-recommendations, home-experiment

I am asking for a book/any other online which has the following quality *(To be particular: Of classical physics(Newtonian mechanics, sounds, lights etc, stuff upto 1800's))*:

> The book, before introducing any particular theory about any natural phenomena, demonstrates and gives example of an good experiment, from which the theory is/can be developed. For example, about the topic Gravitation, before introducing any theories of Newton/Einstien, the puts some experiments which the reader can perform (almost) solely by himself without referring to any external sources, and then the reader can think about it to develop his own explanation/theory for that, and then match it with the existing theories. Regarding the experiment, in that particular case, experiments about observing the moons path, and the eliptical orbit of the planets, and the time swept is proportional to two/third the power of the distance  <sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>*these experiments take a long time, though* :)</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>  could be mentioned.

---

<sub>Notes/Disclaimers:</sub>

<sub>0. Instead of book you can also mention any other source, be online or offline. I am not specifically asking for a list - you may see the linked question to get an idea.</sub>

<sub>1. The books by **Yakov Perelman**, though a bit childish looking at first glance, are excellent. And obviously, **Feyman**'s books are excellent too. I am asking for more sources.</sub>

<sub>2. Experiments which can be done with regular home equipments are more preferred, though feel free to mention any books. Also, thought experiment is counted as an experiments too, so good thought experiment books are okay.</sub>

Comment: This post (v2) seems like a list question.

Comment: What particular branch of physics? Newtonian mechanics? Thermo? QM? Something else?